# Analyze network usage by Individual Applications/Process?

Tags: internet, windows-8

Is there any tool on Win8 to analyze network usage by Applications/Process?

The total network usage seems to be running high, but there are no heavy downloads occuring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Del</kbd> or right click superbar for task manager.
2. Click on more details.
3. Click on App History

There it will display the bandwidth used per app.